# Displaying the text of <a> element from database in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my application.I have a menu on my `master page` which displays all pre-defined menu items(static way) like

1. Home
2. Contact Us
3. About Us

What I would like to accomplish is, I want the text of `<a>` element to be displayed from database , which will be the name of the logged-in user.

Can anybody suggest me as to how I can go about doing this.
Thanks

Comment: so how does the first paragraph releated to question ?

Comment: by static way you mean *hard-coded*. your question is too broad, read more regarding [database integration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I didnot get you , why is it irrelevent.

Comment: @freebird you have a menu. and beside that - you want the logged on user into an <a> element. correct ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I may have not explained my requirement properly but I would like to achieve something like this Home   Contact Us  About Us  RoyiNamir , the users name will be to right of the menu.I hope it makes sense

Comment: can you upload the html where you set the "home...contact us"....?

Comment: @RoyiNamir , I dont mind but it is <ul><li><a>Home</a></li><li><a>Contact Us</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <ul>
    <li>
        <a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><%=Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name %></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

however - you need windows authentications in order to see the real logged on user - otherwise youll see the AppPool user.

p.s. if youre under binding context  : use `<%#`

Comment: ,I am using Forms Authentication , how do I do it then

Comment: try that or HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity worked for me , similarly can I display a column from database table inside anchor tag , is it possible

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly if you want username in the menu and Concatinate  that menu with userName then just store @@username in database with menu and when loading replace @@username with the user

`using String.replace("@@username",strUserName)`